# What is a LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE?

Tags: c, winapi

I can't seem to find any documentation for LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE for the C language.

I found this but it is for .NET Framework 4.5 and it is deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964928.aspx

The reason why I want to know is because I need it for CreateThread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` is actually documented under the name of [`ThreadProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686736.aspx):

> An application-defined function that serves as the starting address for a thread. Specify this address when calling the [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx), [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437.aspx), or [`CreateRemoteThreadEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405484.aspx) function.
>
> **The `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` type defines a pointer to this callback function.** `ThreadProc` is a placeholder for the application-defined function name.

Answer (score 1):

This is [documented here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964928.aspx).  It is a function pointer defined as:

```
typedef DWORD (__stdcall *LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) (
    [in] LPVOID lpThreadParameter
);
```

Comment: In the link you posted, it says ".NET Framework 4.5" http://i.imgur.com/zGKlVGt.png

Comment: @user2899050 That is actually the real docs for that specific type - but it's the same function pointer as a ThreadProc

Comment: @user2899050 Dunno if I reach anyone here but besides that ".NET Framework 4.5" (on the right) there is the option to change the version.