# when do we have to use LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE when creating a thread?

Tags: c++

I have noticed this

```
HandleWorker = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)this->WorkerThread, this, 0, &Id);
```

And I am aware of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472837/what-is-a-lpthread-start-routine), which explains that `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` type defines
starting address for a thread

but can anyone explain to me when do we have to use it? I meant why cant we just use

```
HandleWorker = CreateThread(NULL, 0, this->WorkerThread, this, 0, &Id);
```

Comment: Are you sure this examples works? This argument is an address of the function of a certain signature. It should looks like ` &YourClass:: WorkerThread `.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev, The first one definitely works!

Comment: You don't, when you stick to Standard C++ i.e. `std::thread`. It's quite a bit smarter in figuring out what you passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE is a type defined as a function pointer that takes a void pointer and returns a DWORD.

If `this->WorkerThread` is of that type, you don't have to cast it.